# hsqldb system functions how to use

Tags: hsqldb

Documentation of Hsqldb lists in chapter 4 "Built in Functions" several "System Functions" like for example `DATABASE` or `SESSION_ID`

I can't figure out how to use them? How to get for example the id of the current session? Am I supposed to write SESSION_ID as part of a sql query, if so what would be that complete query? Something like `select SESSION_ID from ...` comes to my mind, but from what?

Can these  functions be called from Java Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All functions can be used in an SQL CALL statement. For example:

```
CALL SESSION_ID()
```

The CALL statement can be executed via JDBC executeQuery(). For example:

```
Connection c = ...;
Statement s = c.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("CALL SESSION_ID");
r.next();
long sessionId = r.getLong(1);
```

A more flexible alternative to the CALL statement is the VALUES statement. This returns a table containing the specified values, which can be constants or results of function calls.

```
ResultSet r1 = s.executeQuery("VALUES SESSION_ID()");

ResultSet r2 = s.executeQuery("VALUES SESSION_ID(), DATABASE()");
```

Comment: ok, thanks. So it always has to be with the brackets like in `executeQuery("CALL SESSION_ID()")`, right?

Comment: Some functions such as SESSION_USER can be used with or without the brackets.  This is shown in http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_system_functions